# Boundary detection from Segmenation file (ascii cr)

Tags: python, numpy

I am working on defining the img_segmentation for segments present in different human objects in ascii cr format. I have managed to write the below code so far to detect boundary

[image]

```
def  load_data(self,img_int : int )-> Tuple[ np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    """
    Given the integer value of the image, load the image and 
    the corresponding segmentation map. The segmentation map is the union of 
    all the human annotations.
    Inputs:
        - img_int : integer value of the image
    Outputs:
        - img : H x W x D image 
        - img_seg : H x W binary segmentation map
    Note: 
        - 1 for boundary and 0 for non-boundary
    """
    img_file = os.path.join(self.image_path, f"{img_int}.jpg")
    if not os.path.isfile(img_file):
        raise FileNotFoundError(f"Image file '{img_file}' not found.")
    img = plt.imread(img_file)
    img_seg = self.load_seg(img_int, img.shape[:2])
    return img, img_seg

 
def load_seg(self, img_int : int , img_shape : Tuple) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Load the segmentation map for the image from all the human annotations
    Inputs:
        - img_int : integer value of the image
        - img_shape : shape of the image 
    Outputs:
        - img_seg : H x W binary segmentation map
    """
    if not isinstance(img_shape, tuple) or len(img_shape) != 2:
        raise ValueError("img_shape must be a tuple of two elements (height, width).")

    # Initialize a binary segmentation map
    img_seg = np.zeros(img_shape, dtype=np.uint8)

    # Construct the list of segmentation files for this image
    seg_files = [os.path.join(self.seg_path, human_subj, f"{img_int}.seg") 
                for human_subj in os.listdir(self.seg_path) 
                if os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.seg_path, human_subj, f"{img_int}.seg"))]
    
    for seg_file in seg_files:
        
        with open(seg_file, 'r') as file:
            # Skip the initial lines
            lines = file.readlines()
            data_lines = lines[12:]
            # Initialize a temporary segmentation map for the current file
            temp_seg_map = np.zeros(img_shape, dtype=np.uint8)
            for line in data_lines:
                line_vars = line.strip().split()
                s, row, c1, c2 = [int(var) for var in line_vars]
                if s != 0 and row < img_shape[0] and c1 < img_shape[1] and c2 < img_shape[1]:
                    temp_seg_map[row, c1:c2+1] = s
        # Combine the individual segmentation with the overall map
        img_seg = np.logical_or(img_seg, temp_seg_map)
    print(f"Total boundary pixels in image {img_int}: {np.sum(img_seg)}")
    return img_seg
```

Now, I want to detect other boundaries in other segments so that I detect all pixels present in the seg file.

Right now, when I am running the test, it shows that `Segmentation not loaded correctly`

What I missing here?